# warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.List

Tags: java, jsf, ant, javac

I am getting warning

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the 
raw type java.util.List
    [javac]      listbox.getChildren().add(listaMenu);
```

where `listaMenu` is declared as

```
UISelectItems listaMenu = new UISelectItems();
```

and `listbox` is declared as

```
HtmlSelectOneListbox listbox = new HtmlSelectOneListbox();
```

How can I get rid of this warning message when I compile using ant build tasks?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either get a new version of the Faces API implementation you're using (one that supports generics), or put `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` just before the start of the function (right before where `public` or `private` would go).

Comment: I have added as     `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
public HtmlSelectOneListbox myMethod() {` however I am still getting warning message when I compile my project. Thanks

Comment: It needs to be applied to every function that makes unchecked calls (ie, add it to each function that's generating warnings, and I expect there'll be quite a few of them). Some IDEs (such as eclipse) may have an option somewhere to auto-add ('quick fix') the suppress warnings annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Add an annotation to suppress the warning if the JSF API forces the use of unchecked casting:

```
@SuppressWarnings(value = "unchecked")
```

Similar to the answer(s) given here: [Java [unchecked] unchecked case warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631537/java-unchecked-unchecked-case-warning)